# Select the first record in a one to many relation using left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables using a left-join. And the result set has to include only the first record from the "right" joined table.

Let's say I have two tables products and product_translations as below;

**Table 'products'**

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 150 |

**Table 'product_translations'**

| id | product_id | lang | column | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | en | title | Product 1 Title |
| 2 | 2 | en | title | Product 2 Title |
| 3 | 1 | en | description | Product 1 Description |
| 4 | 2 | en | description | Product 2 Description |
| 5 | 1 | de | title | Produkt 1 Titel |
| 6 | 2 | de | title | Produkt 2 Titel |
| 7 | 1 | de | description | Produkt 1 Beschreibung |
| 8 | 2 | de | description | Produkt 2 Beschreibung |

**Expected output**

| id | price | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Product 1 Title | Product 1 Description |
| 2 | 150 | Product 2 Title | Product 2 Description |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't want the "first" row, but just two different ones based on the language. So you need to joins to the translation table: one for the "title" and one for the "description"

```
select p.*, t.description as title, d.description
from product p
  left join product_translations t 
         on t.product_id = p.id 
        and t.language = 'en'
        and t.column = 'title'
  left join product_translations d 
         on d.product_id = p.id 
        and d.language = 'en'
        and d.column = 'description'
```

If you want to retrieve this with a "primary" and "fallback" language, you can do something like this:

```
with product_texts as (
  select t.product_id, t.value as title, d.value as description, t.lang
  from product_translations t
    join product_translations d 
      on d.product_id = t.product_id
     and d.lang = t.lang
     and d."column" = 'description'
  where t."column" = 'title'   
    and t.product_id = 3
    and t.lang in ('de', 'en')
) 
select t.*
from product_texts t
order by case 
           when t.lang = 'de' then 1
           else 2
         end
limit 1
```

As it is a bit complicated to always join against that, you can create a function that does this:

```
create function get_translations(p_product_id int, p_lang text, p_fallback_lang text default 'en')
  returns table (product_id int, title text, description text, lang text)
as
$$ 
  with product_texts as (
    select t.product_id, t.value as title, d.value as description, t.lang
    from product_translations t
      join product_translations d 
        on d.product_id = t.product_id
       and d.lang = t.lang
       and d."column" = 'description'
    where t."column" = 'title'   
      and t.product_id = 3
      and t.lang in (p_lang, p_fallback_lang)
  ) 
  select t.*
  from product_texts t
  order by case 
             when t.lang = p_lang then 1
             else 2
           end
  limit 1
$$
language sql
rows 1
stable;
```

Then you can do:

```
select *
from products p
  left join lateral get_translations(p.id, 'de', 'en') on true
```

There is next to none overhead in calling the function as this will be inlined - just as if you had written the function's query into the main query.

For good performance you want an index on `(product_id, lang, "column")` or maybe even two filtered indexes:

```
create index product_lang_title 
  on product_translations (product_id, lang)
where "column" = 'title';

create index product_lang_descr 
   on product_translations (product_id, lang)
where "column" = 'description';
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=63c436ab411f78d219858d62beb6510e)

Comment: Okay, it's worked for me but
If I want to prioritize language? For example, language is 'de', but a product with id 1 doesn't have 'de' title translation and I need to get 'en' one

Comment: @SSWiking: you should have put that directly into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought of that now

Comment: Can you improve your answer to my needing, please?

Comment: @SSWiking see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Use a row_number to define the first row. I've assumed you mean "first record" is the one with the lowest "id" value.

```
with prod_t as
(
  select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by product_id, t1.column order by id) as rn
  from product_translations t1
)
select p1.*, t2.value as title, t3.value as desctiption
from products p1
left join prod_t t2
  on t2.product_id = p1.id
  and t2.column = 'title'
  and rn =1
left join prod_t t3
  on t3.product_id = p1.id
  and t3.column = 'description'
  and rn =1
```

Also, it is best to avoid using "column" as a column name